# Values from View to Controller not recieved

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

My View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("RegisterNewUser ", "RegisterUser", new { @class = "registerForm" }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.nickName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.nickName, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
    <br /><br />

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.email)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.email, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.email)
    <br /><br />

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "RegisterControls", id = "firstPassword" })
    <br /><br />

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { @class = "RegisterControls" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.confirmPassword)
    <br /><br /><br />
    <hr style="color: #D5E0EE; border: solid; border-style: double;" />

    @Ajax.ActionLink("Create account", "RegisterNewUser", "RegisteredUsers", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "updaterDiv", HttpMethod = "POST" }, new { @class = "actionButtons" })
    <br /><br />
```

My controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(string uName, string email, string password)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Register";
        string msg = "";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(uName, email, password))
        {
            msg = "The provided email already exists";
        }

        ViewBag.Message = msg;
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

When I set a break point at the Action method, I see that all three parameters are null, even when they are provided in the textboxes. What am I missing. I could also add the model code, but I guess this is not yet relevant, as it's not involved yet.

-------------------------------------Update----------------------------------

Hi. I have introduced a submit button to my view, and removed the Ajax ActionLink. So the view now contains this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="@Url.Action("RegisterNewUser", "RegisterUsers");" class="actionButtons" />
```

And I changed the parameter of the Action method to take a model, so it now looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(RegisteredUsers registerUserModel)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Register";
        string msg = "";

        if (!users.RegisterUser(registerUserModel.nickName, registerUserModel.email, registerUserModel.password))
        {
            msg = "The provided email already exists";
        }
        return PartialView("_Register");            
    }
```

The problem is the same, the values are still null. This time when setting a breakpoint, I notice that the submit button is not calling the Action method. The submit button actually does nothing when clicked. I have also tried not adding the onclick event listener as I see in some examples, but result remains the same.

In case it is needed, the model looks like this:

```
public class RegisteredUsers
{
    private DBLogic logic;

    [Display(Name ="Your Email")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must provide a valid Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select a user name", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name="User name")]
    public string nickName { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Select a password", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [Display(Name="Password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Type your password again")]
    [Display(Name="Confirm password")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage="The two passwords do not match")]
    public string confirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Remember me")]
    public bool rememberUserOnThisComputer { get; set; }
public void ...
```

Comment: You have `Html.BeginForm()`. You need a submit button - `<input type="submit" ..>` and remove the `Ajax.ActionLink()`. And since you have a model, you should post back the model - `public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(YourModel model)`, not value types. And if you want to stay on the same page, use `Ajax.BeginForm()` instead of `Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: Re: your edit. Do not add the the `onclick`. It just needs to be `<input type="submit" value="Register" class="actionButtons" />` and your also using the wrong overload of `BeginForm()` - your setting a route value `class=registerForm`, not a html attribute.

Comment: What does it mean that I am setting a route value and not a html attribute? How should it be?

Comment: Look at the html you generating in the form tag to understand. The various overloads are  [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `Ajax.BeginForm` instead with just a normal input button.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("RegisterNewUser ", "RegisterNewUser ", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" }))    
{
  <div id="result"></div>
  ...form data
  <input type="submit" value="Ajax Form Action" />
}
```

You could also change your controller method to take the model object as the parameter. 
This way you would not need to specify each parameter.

Without seeing your model something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RegisterNewUser(RegisterModel model)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Register";
    string msg = "";

    if (!users.RegisterUser(model.uName, model.email, model.password))
    {
        msg = "The provided email already exists";
    }

    ViewBag.Message = msg;
    return PartialView("_Register");            
}
```

Comment: I am very new with asp.net mvc, and the info you guys gave me here is priceless. Thanks for that.
Back to the code... What is the use of the Html.BeginForm if it doesn't send the values? When is it prefered over the other?

Comment: @user1960836 No probs. `Html.BeginForm` is for a traditional post without Ajax. This article compares the two and is worth a read. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC

Comment: @user1960836, Html.BeginForm does post the values - its just that you did not have a submit button.